# Github push -f origin master - Size has gone up and it takes too long to push

Tags: git, github

I keep a repository on github for my project just in case I ever lose my computer. I only use three steps: 
 1. git add.
 2. git commit -m "name"
 3. git push -f origin master

This has been working fine until today. I made some really minor changes to the app, and suddenly the push started taking too long. I solved the "takes too long" part by running this:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

It solved the first problem, but unfortunately the process of uploading to github does not end, and I see a file size way too big for my project. Here is my log when I push now. The process stops at the last line forever.

```
git push -f origin master
Enumerating objects: 38, done.
Counting objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 135.68 MiB | 157.35 MiB/s, done.
Total 20 (delta 12), reused 8 (delta 1)
```

**Another option I considered** is that github is down. I try to enter their website without success but my Internet is fine. Could this be an explanation? This problem I explain has persisted for 12+ hours so I doubt github has been down that long.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. There was a big file created out of nowhere called java_pid111776 in the android folder. It was 600 Mb.

I deleted it, had to reset the github repo, restart my .git project folder and add again. It works now (although it may not be the best solution, it works for me).